# Kotlin - Can you import a class only to define the existence of it and redeclare it in another module

Tags: kotlin, import, classpath

Let's say I have module `A` with class `Model`.

Module `B` has an interface `MyInterface` which has `foo(A.Model)`.  However, B cannot depend on A for reasons not explained here.

```
import a.Model  // does not have access

interface MyInterface {
   fun foo(a: Model)
}
```

I want MyInterface to be able to receive A.Model even though it is not completely declared in B. In other words, I would like B to have knowledge of a class A.Model.

If I redeclare a.Model in B I guess it will mark duplicated class. And I don't want to have an interface b.Model to create the following because it will break other design rules:

```
data class Model: b.Model {
   ..
}



 A module:

    a/
      Module.kt


 B module:
    b/
      MyInterface.kt
      Module.kt  // This would mean to create an Interface
    a/
      Module.kt  // This would mean to re-define class
```

Is there another way to simply let my class know of the existence of something that will compile when resolving the complete classpath?

Comment: Why doesn't B have access to A? As you've modelled your program right now, B has a clear dependency on A, even when you don't want to express it explicitly.

Comment: *B cannot depend on A*, but you're going to put A on the classpath when compiling B? I don't quite get it. What does it mean for B not to depend on A in your mind?

Comment: You could invert the dependency control by providing a own Model interface inside B, which is then used on the api surface of B. This way, you don't couple B to A. However, then you have to add some glue code to bridge between the Model from A to use with the api surface of B.

Comment: How can `a.Model` be duplicated if you don't depend on A module? Do you mean that A won't be available at compile time, but it will be provided at runtime?

Comment: @broot I mean that it can be duplicated if I re-declare the a.Model (meaning a package) class in the B module

Comment: I still don't understand. If you don't include A module then this is like it doesn't at all exist. Then you can create `a.Module` in B and it won't duplicate anything. Your situation is really unclear to me. If A is included then you can use it normally. if it is not included then there is no point in referencing its components.

Comment: @htafoya it might be a wording issue. Are you trying to compile B without A on the compile classpath, but with the intention of having A on the runtime classpath when running your application? If that's the case, it's simply not possible: you can't compile code without having the proper declarations on the compile classpath. But you could organize modules differently by adding a 3rd module for the public interface (provided on the compile classpath) and put the implementation of A only on the runtime classpath. What are you trying to achieve by "B not depending on A"?